# Get FirstName, LastName and other from OpenId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

[Here](http://pastebin.com/yQJT9Pia) the relevant functions from the ASP.NET MVC template.

How do I get some additional attributes of the user such as FirstName etc? I don't mind using `DotNetOpenAuth`, if there is no other choice, I obviously prefer the in-box version.

I'm unsure what I have to change there to make it work, I don't want to mess it all up.

Comment: The answer very much depends on which provider you want the data from. If it's an OpenID Provider, that's one thing. If it is an OAuth service provider then it's specific to each one. I see you have both OpenID and OAuth tags on your question, but your title only says "OpenID". Please clarify.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Please take a look at [the code linked in my question](http://pastebin.com/yQJT9Pia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is you can't. The ASP.MVC template makes *login* easy, but that's pretty much all it is. Just authentication. It provides little or no information about the user other than it's the same user that was here before.

If you want to get additional information for the user, I suggest you handle more of the login yourself. An example of how to do this is in the OpenIdRelyingParty MVC sample that you can [download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/releases/v4.2/v4.2.2/DotNetOpenAuth-4.2.2.13055.zip/download).